# Rails 3: define plugin gem dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, dependencies, rubygems

I wrote a plugin that requires a gem as a dependency.

Where do I have to define this dependency?

I have tried to create a Gemfile in vendor/plugins/my_plugin/, but `bundle install` doesn‛t find this file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok. I have solved.

**1)** Create a **Gemfile** in vendor/plugins/my_plugin like:

```
# Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"
gemspec
```

**2)** Create a **gemspec** file. In the folder *vendor/plugins* run this command:

```
bundle gem my_plugin
```

(Note this command ask you for overwrite some files. Check the files before answer: Y)

**3)** Open **gemspec** file in vendor/plugins/my_plugin/ and add before the keyword end:

```
s.add_dependency('will_paginate', '~> 3.0.pre2')
```

(In this example I have used will_paginate how required dipendency of my_plugin)

**4)** Now go in your rails app and edit **Gemfile**, add:

```
gem 'my_plugin', :path=>'vendor/plugins/my_plugin'
```

The path specified supposed that your plugin is already in vendor/plugins folder of your rails app.
Of course when deploy rails app you don't need anymore to specify **:path** argument.

**5)** Now in rails app root do:

```
bundle install
```

And **dependency** of my_plugin (will_paginate in this case) is installed.

Thank to Sinetris for initial input.

Comment: I've a similar problem, but in my case its not a plugin, its a engine/gem. I did as you said, the `bundle install` installs the gems as dependencies. But it appears that the application doesn't load those gems, or initialize them, causing errors of undefined methods everywhere. The engine by itself works ok. Do you have any idea what could be missing?

Comment: I have the same issue as Tiago, but mine *is* a plugin. `bundle install` installs all the dependencies – I see them in Gemfile.lock – but they aren't loaded by Rails. What's missing?

Comment: I had to move my init.rb to rails/init.rb which seams to be loaded after the rails application i loaded. Also I had problems accessing `Rails.root` while loading the lib code, solved it by moving some init code to rails/init.rb.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Gemfile in your vendor/plugins/my_plugin/ like:

```
# Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"
gemspec

gem "your-dependency-gem-name"
```

note the gemspec directive.

Take a look at [Using Bundler with Rubygem gemspecs](http://gembundler.com/rubygems.html) for more information.

Comment: Ok. I perhaps have started from the mistaken assumption that the command 'bundle install' looking in folder vendor/plugins and resolve the dependencies at development time of the plugin. If understand now, I need to make a gem of the my plugin first and its dependencies will be resolved when my plugin will be installed. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Sebtm's own answer is quite good, but it still didn't work as Tiago and orangechicken described. I had to add

```
require 'your-dependency-gem-name'
```

on top of `lib/my_plugin.rb` right before the engine of `my_plugin` is loaded.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#other-gem-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile in the application folder.

```
# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3
```

Comment: I need to specify gem dependency for plugin, not for application

Answer (score 0):

Reference for myself. If you're making a plugin that should work with Rails as a RailTie, use `rails plugin my_plugin` to create the gem instead of `bundle gem my_plugin`. It saves you (me) a lot of trouble.

Edit: When do you need the gem to work as a RailTie? Whenever you want to add **rails generator**, **rake tasks** or add your code to a Rails app (Called *Rails Engine*).
/Edit

```
$ rails plugin new my_plugin
```

then you add dependencies

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
  #...
  s.add_dependency "rails"
  s.add_runtime_dependency "heroku"
  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

to include it in your rails app, use `path:` as described by @Sebtm

or release it to rubygems.

```
$ gem build my_plugin.gemspec
$ gem push my_plugin-0.7.0.gem #replace version number
#in Gemfile, as always
gem 'my_plugin'
```

or tag it on github. (use their release UI) and depend on it using

```
 gem 'my_plugin', github: 'accountname/my_plugin', tag: 'v0.7.0'
```

Comment: If you need it to work as a RailTie for Rails. When do you want that? Whenever you want to add **rails generator**, **rake tasks** or add your code to a Rails app (Called *Rails Engine*). If you need none of that, don't use `rails plugin`.